# How to append 3 bytes '110' at the end of NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sockets

HERE IS THE CODE->

```
NSString* message = @"username,password";
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:
                       [message dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[data appendBytes:"0x1""0x1""0x0"
               length:3];
```

I am expecting output -> username,password110

but not getting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are appending is not bytes, it's a string `"0x10x10x0"`. The first three characters get appended - specifically, `'0'`, `'x'`, and `'1'`.

To append three bytes, create a byte array, and append it:

```
unsigned char suffixBytes[] = {1, 1, 0};
[data appendBytes:suffixBytes length:3];
```

In one specific case, when all bytes represent character codes of printable characters, you can use a string literal instead:

```
[data appendBytes:"110" length:3];
```

This will append character codes of `'1'`, `'1'`, and `'0'` to your data. Assuming ASCII encoding, the values would be `{0x31, 0x31, 0x30}`.

Comment: NSMutableData* lobjdata = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        
    unsigned char suffixBytes[] = {1, 1, 0};
    [lobjdata appendBytes:suffixBytes length:3];
        
     NSLog(@"bytes -> %@",lobjdata);

Comment: @UA_PPS OK. So what gets printed when you do that?

Comment: @UA_PPS Is that what you expected to append, or did you want to append `313130` (ASCII codes of `110`)? What happens when you long your data right after the `initWithData` call?

Comment: hey thanks to u for quick response. I wanna send  data to the server using NSOutputStream and server is expecting last three bytes to 110, for example -> 'username,password,1,1,0' something like that

Comment: @UA_PPS So what do you get when you `NSLog` your `lobjdata` before the append?

Comment: NSString* message = @"username,password";
        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:
                               [message dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        
       
        
        unsigned char suffixBytes[] = {1, 1, 0};
        [data appendBytes:suffixBytes length:3];
        
        NSLog(@"bytes -> %@",data);
output-><75736572 6e616d65 2c706173 73776f72 64010100>

Comment: but I wanna my last three bytes 110, so server can understand message is end

Comment: packets sent to the server should be terminated by a 3-byte sequence of 1, 1, 0 (literal byte values, not strings), in order to be recognized.

Comment: @UA_PPS What do you mean by `110`? Each byte is shown with two characters in hex, so `01 01 00` in hex is `1, 1, 0` That's the packet that you get then.

Comment: server is expecting last three bytes of message will be 110

Comment: so i m trying to get that

Comment: @UA_PPS That's what they are - the actual thee last bytes are 1, 1, and 0. It's just the way the `NSLog` prints them.

Comment: ok, thanks buddy, I am explaing what I understand from ur answer NSLog prints in HEX thats why its showing 6 digit instead of three digits but they are actually three bytes.

Comment: @UA_PPS Yes, in hex one byte == 2 hex digits.